# How do I keep the two objects from penetrating each other in Blender?

Tags: physics

I created the object by first creating the edges to the curved face with the script below followed by adding a face and then extruding it. I made sure to change the Source property under Collision to Base but still the objects penetrate each other. How do I prevent this? Any help would be much appreciated. It has been too long that I have been struggling with this :(

[image]

```
import bpy
import math
from math import sin, cos, radians, sqrt

# variables
n_verts = 24
profile_radius = 1
section_angle = 240.0 / (n_verts-1) 
z_float = 0.0
Verts = []
Edges = []
Faces = []

# code for bottom face
for i in range(n_verts):
    x_float = cos(-math.pi/6+math.radians(section_angle*i))
    y_float = 1 + sin(-math.pi/6+math.radians(section_angle*i))
    Verts.append((x_float, y_float, z_float))
    
for i in range(1, n_verts):
    x_float = -math.sqrt(3)/2 + cos(math.pi/2+math.radians(section_angle*i))
    y_float = -1/2 + sin(math.pi/2+math.radians(section_angle*i))
    Verts.append((x_float, y_float, z_float))

for i in range(1, n_verts-1):
    x_float = math.sqrt(3)/2 + cos(-5*math.pi/6+math.radians(section_angle*i))
    y_float = -1/2 + sin(-5*math.pi/6+math.radians(section_angle*i))
    Verts.append((x_float, y_float, z_float))

# connect all the edges
for i in range(3*n_verts-3):
    if i == 3*n_verts-4:
        Edges.append([i, 0])
        break
    Edges.append([i, i+1])

profile_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Base_Profile_Data")
profile_mesh.from_pydata(Verts, Edges, Faces)
profile_mesh.update()

profile_object = bpy.data.objects.new("Base_Profile", profile_mesh)
profile_object.data = profile_mesh

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.collection.objects.link(profile_object)
profile_object.select_set(True)
```

[image: Frame 1]

[image: Frame 50]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: hey I have uploaded the file

Comment: I'm not an expert enough in Rigid Body, you can fix the problem if you switch from (Shape >) Mesh to Convex Hull but maybe I miss a solution with Mesh

Comment: hey man, thanks. that helps a LOT! :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the surface Normals are facing *inwards* and this is breaking the collision.

To resolve this, select each object and go into Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and select Mesh/Normals/Recalculate Outside. This should re-calculate the normals so that they are consistent with a solid object. Once you have done this for both objects, re-run the simulation and the collision should now be working correctly.

Bad normals
[image]

Good normals
[image]

Comment: hey thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem if you go in the *Properties panel > Physics > Collisions* and you switch the *Shape* from *Mesh* to *Convex Hull*. I hope someone will explain why *Mesh* fails or if I miss the right settings, it might be because Blender can't deal with too complex topologies?

[image]